# File Download using Asp.net Web Api and Angular 8

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular8

Hi I recently started working on angular and I have a requirement to create and download excel file using asp.net web api and angular 8

I created excel file using Asp.net Web API and returning file as

`return File(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "test.xlsx");`

I have to read this excel file using angular and download

```
GetExportExcel(editQuoteFilters: EditQuoteModel):Observable<any>{ 
      let postHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
      postHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      postHeaders.append('responseType', 'blob');
      return this.http.post<any>(this.ExcelExportLevel0ApiUrl, editQuoteFilters,{ headers: postHeaders, 
           responseType : 'arraybuffer' as 'json'})                                      
          .pipe(map((res) =>{
                  var blob = new Blob([res.blob()], {type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"})
                  return blob
                })
          );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

`import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';`

```
this.http.post(this.ExcelExportLevel0ApiUrl, editQuoteFilters, { responseType: 'blob' }).subscribe((resp: any) => {
   let fileName = "test";
   FileSaver.saveAs(resp, `${fileName}.xlsx`);
});
```

[Stackbiltz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z4adjy?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Following is working for me 

this.http.post<any>(this.ExcelExportLevel0ApiUrl, editQuoteFilters,{responseType : 'blob' as 'json'})
                      .pipe(map((res: any) => {
                        return new Blob([res],{type:'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'})
                      })).subscribe(data => saveAs(data,'InventoryUploadStatus'));

Comment: Great :) Please mark the answer as correct if this was useful